# ASP.NET MVC Entity Framework Relationship binding

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, relationship

I'm using Entity Framework 5.0 for my MVC4 project. There's a problem with it. When i give a db model to any view, controller send model with no relationship

example;

I have User class and with relation departments

when i use it in controller

```
using(context)
{
  var user = context.Find(id);
  string department = user.Department.Name;
}
```

its working when call in context. but when i do that

```
using(context)
{
  var user = context.Find(id);
  return View(user);
}
```

and call in view like

```
Model.Department.Name
```

i got error.

Here is my answer but its not good

```
using(context)
{
  var user = context.Find(id);
  string department = user.Department.Name;
  return View(user);
}
```

when i try to user Model.Department.Name in view i got no error i must do that for every relation when i use class as model. there is have better solution for this problem ? i want use all relationship in View without call these in controller.

I hope you can understand me, sorry my english.

Comment: What error are you getting at all?

Comment: "The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection." Its the error i can fix it with call relations at controller but i dont want call them all all the time there should have a binding function or something with ef

Comment: Have you tried instead of Model.Department.Name to have Model.User in the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your DbContext you could use the `.Include` method to eagerly load the relations you need:

```
context.Users.Include(u => u.Department).FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
```

or if you are using an older version of entity Framework the generic version of this method might not be available:

```
context.Users.Include("Department").FirstOrDefault(u => u.Id == id);
```

Comment: Ok i got it Darin, here is another question about this. I have older version 5.0 ef. there another realtionship too like 

var alluserInYourDepartment = User.Department.Users;

what about that Include method include it ? :)

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is that you haven't "loaded" the Department in your original code. As your context is wrapped in a using statement it's being disposed of before the view is created and therefore your user object lacks the data you want.

In your second code example you have specifically called into the related Department object and therefore it now exists within the User object.

You need to eager load the Department in your original line using something like

```
context.User.Include(c => c.Department).Find(id);
```

Now your user object should have this available in the view.

Comment: here is another question about this. I have older version 5.0 ef. there another realtionship too like var alluserInYourDepartment = User.Department.Users; what about that Include method include it ? :)

Comment: Without seeing more of the code it's hard to help. I think you need to read up on how EF works. Assuming your models have the proper navigation properties (so your Department has a public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; } property) then you should be able to use User.Department.Users as you suggest to get all users from the department for a given user. I've tried a very simple test here and it worked without further includes.

Comment: mvc3-4 ? ef 4.0 or 5.0 or 6.0 which one is your using ?

Comment: I'm using MVC4 and EF 5.0 but I believe this concept should apply to all versions.

Answer (score 1):

What are u trying to accomplish? List a view for a user with one or many departments?

Comment: no, think like that i have vehicles, vehiclerequests, vehiclerequestapproves. When i want see vehicle request detail at view
 i should see which user did what like user a approved user b cancel user c didnt response. so i must do that for each request.Approves
approve.User.Username like that so its mean one include didnt enougth